# Storing Potentially Large Amounts of Data with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm working on an app that lets users store items in different collections. Each item contains the item name, price, UPC, and any images the user associates with it either from the camera or from photo albums. The issue I'm seeing with using Core Data is that there could be issues if the user has a ton of items in their collections. I'm wanting to have this available completely offline. How should I go about this?

Comment: What issues? Your question is very vague. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm just concerned with storing the data locally with Core Data. It's very possible that a user could have thousands of items in a collection and that concerns me.

Comment: Concerns you how? Again, this is too vague. What is your clear and specific programming question?

Comment: Basically, is Core Data my best option or should I use something else? Is Core Data ok for storing very large amounts of data?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? It would be implemented on top of sqlite which is a relational database.

Comment: I guess I'm just concerned with device storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQLite, Core Data can handle more data than you have physical space on an iOS device.  SQLite has been used to store *terabytes* of data.  Core Data handles the memory management extremely well.  The combination makes the quantity of data a non-issue.